Sound gone after upgrade from UbuntuStudio 22.04 to 24.04.1
I caved and let the upgrade nag happen on my main desktop box last night.
This is an AMD Ryzen 7 (2nd gen), ASUS ROG motherboard, 64g RAM.
Upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04 went smoothly except for one, apparently non-critical, error.
Upon reboot, no sound and the Audio menu item from the menu bar says, "No output or input devices found." I have a built-in sound system (obviously for the ROG mboards) and an external Focusrite Scarlett i4 attached via USB.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I went through all the installed sound packages and discovered that ubuntustudio-audio-core failed to install in the upgrade.
To install that package run:
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ubuntustudio-audio-core

Rebooted (didn't bother to monkey with the daemon) and it's working and now and sees all of my I/O options.
